# Creat a class called Investment with fields named principal and interest rate

Tags: python, class, object-oriented-analysis

I have the following problem.
Write a class called Investment with fields called principal and interest. The constructor should set the values of those fields. There should be a method called value_after that
returns the value of the investment after n years. The formula for this is `p(1 + i)n`, where `p` is the principal, and `i` is the interest rate.

I've already created a class and those asked methods.

```
class Investment:
    def __init__(self,principal,interest_rate):
        self.principal=principal
        self.interest_rate=interest_rate
    def value_after(self):
        n=int(input('Number of years\n'))
        return self.principal(1+self.interest_rate)**n    

final_result=Investment(float(input('Digit principal\n')),float(input('Digit interest rate\n')))
print('Final result is',final_result.value_after)
```

I expect to print the final result given in value_after function but when i run the program it gets the following warning:
Final result is `<bound method Investment.value_after of <__main__.Investment object at 0x7f0760110850>>`

Comment: value_after is function call it like : final_result.value_after()

Comment: I've done that but after asking me the years it gives an error saying float object is not callable

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: In your code you have `self.principal(1+self.interest_rate)`. `self.principal` is a number but you try to call it like a function. Do you miss an operator before the opening parantheses?

Comment: thanks . Talking about identation stackoverflow way of posting code is different now

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your code (and it was the same as in the years before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have an indentation problem, the two line after `def value_after(self):` must be indented with respect to it: value_after has no body at all with your indentation.

PS: I see you corrected it :-)

Answer (score 0):

call the function using () and add an operator (I have added a * operator) after the variable self.principal in return statement. This will fix errors:

```
class Investment:

    def __init__(self,principal,interest_rate):
        self.principal=principal
        self.interest_rate=interest_rate
    def value_after(self):
        n=int(input('Number of years\n'))
        return self.principal*(1+self.interest_rate)**n    

final_result=Investment(float(input('Digit principal\n')),float(input('Digit interest rate\n')))

print('Final result is',final_result.value_after())
```

Comment: Maybe `value_after` should get the value `n` as a parameter, but we don't know that from the question. In real life coding one would never use `input` in this method.

Comment: I've already came up with the error. I cannot return self.principal(1+self.interest_rate). Python does not work like we do with multiplication i have to do self.principal*(1+self.interest_rate)